# how to count number of values in for a key in an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

How to count number of values for a key in JS object ?

if you have an object like this

```
{
a: 'text1', 'text2', 'text3'
}
```

or this is not possible to be in the format above because `,` means that it will be a new key. and to hold more than one value it must be `a: [val1 , val2 , val3]`.

Comment: What are you asking? And did you try setting this up to do some testing before you came here?

Comment: yes i've tried, but i find some difficultly in understanding objects. that's why i'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is not correct.
You need to assign `a` an array if you want it to hold multiple values, like so:

```
const obj = {
  a: ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
}
console.log(obj.a.length);
```